# Pytorch: How to generate random vectors with length in a certain range?

Tags: python, numpy, random, pytorch

I want a `k` by `3` by `n` tensor representing `k` batches of `n` random 3d vectors, each vector has a magnitude (Euclidean norm) between `a` and `b`. Other than rescaling the entries of a random `kx3xn` tensor to `n` random lengths in a for loop, is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to bound the entries of the tensor, or the vectors in it. If the latter, which norm are you referring to when you write *magnitude* of a vector (Euclidean etc.)?

Comment: @7shoe I'm trying to bound the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a < b`, you now have a constraint on the 3rd random number due to the norm. i.e  `sqrt(a^2 - x^2 - y^2) < z < sqrt(b^2 - x^2 - y^2)`

Now `a^2 - x^2 - y^2 > 0` which implies that `x^2 + y^2 < a^2`

We need two sets of generate numbers such that `x^2 + y^2 < a^2`

```
import numpy as np

def rand_generator(a,b,n,k):

    req_array = np.zeros((n,k,3))
    # first generate random numbers for x i.e 0<x<a
    
    req_array[:,:,0] = np.random.rand(n,k)*a
    
    # now generate random numbers for y such that 0 < y < a^-x2

    req_array[:,:,1] = np.random.rand( n,k) * np.sqrt(a**2 - req_array[:,:,0]**2)
    
    norm_temp = np.linalg.norm(req_array,axis=2)

    a1 = np.sqrt(a**2 - norm_temp**2) 

    b1 = np.sqrt(b**2 - norm_temp**2)
    
    # generate numbers for z such that they are inbetween a1 and b1

    req_array[:,:,2] = a1 + np.random.rand(n,k)*(b1-a1)

    return req_array


ll = rand_generator(2,5,10,12)
lp = np.linalg.norm(ll,axis=2)

print(np.all(lp>2) and np.all(lp<5))

##output: True
```

---

You can also use spherical coordinates for this(which is exactly same as above)
`x = rsin(theta)cos(phi)`, `y = rsin(theta)sin(phi)`, `z = rcos(theta)` with  `a< r <b` `0<theta<pi/2` and `0<phi<pi/2`

```
import numpy as np

def rand_generator(a,b,n,k):

    req_array = np.zeros((n,k,3))
    # first generate random numbers for r in [a,b)
    
    r = a + np.random.rand(n,k)*(b-a)
    
    # now generate random numbers for theta in [0,pi/2)

    theta = np.random.rand( n,k) * np.pi/2
    
    # now generate random numbers for phi in [0,pi/2)

    phi = np.random.rand( n,k) * np.pi/2

    req_array[:,:,0] = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi)
 
    req_array[:,:,1] = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
    
    req_array[:,:,2] = r*np.cos(theta)
    
    return req_array


ll = rand_generator(2,5,10,12)
lp = np.linalg.norm(ll,axis=2)

print(np.all(lp>2) and np.all(lp<5))

##output: True
```